# gmaps geometa.js not found?

Tags: maps, google-geolocation

I'm using a plugin which calls http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocate/geometa.js for displaying map with pins on the homepage. However, this link is not found (404). I've searched for the solution too see what to do, but with no luck.

Is there a new version of this javascript available that I could replace this link with the new one? Not sure how else to put it and hope it makes sense.

Comment: Need this also some idiot who made a WP plugin used this and its breaking things now. I don't understand people using links to code that isn't permanent in public released stuff.

Comment: Yeah.. Same thing here. I found that link already but I thought there is a newer version.. I'll try to load it from my own server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not Certain but I think this is the file.

http://pastebin.com/D22BSvb8

EDIT: Think this is the most upto date version: http://pastebin.com/GHpyPTQE